# [Azure/mssql]How do I get Insert query recordset

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, express, azure-sql-database

I'm using mssql.
After inserting a record,I want to get the id of the data.
But I don't know hot to do that.
My code is below.
please give me answer.

```
var mssql = require('mssql');
mssql.connect(config.mssql, function(err) {
var request = new mssql.Request(); 
request.query('insert -----'),function(err, data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```

Insert worked properly,but console log is [undefined] ....

---

this is the ddl of the table

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Feature](
    [id] nvarchar NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Feature_id]  DEFAULT (CONVERT(nvarchar,newid(),(0))),
    [createdAt] datetimeoffset NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Feature_createdAt]  DEFAULT (CONVERT(datetimeoffset,sysutcdatetime(),(0))),
    [updatedAt] datetimeoffset NULL,
    [version] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [deleted] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [title] nvarchar NULL,
    [text] nvarchar NULL,
    [period_from] datetimeoffset NULL,
    [period_to] datetimeoffset NULL,
    [priority] [float] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)

GO

Comment: For a singleton insert, you could add `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the `INSERT` statement in the same batch. Alternatively, specify an `OUTPUT` clause (OUTPUT inserted.ID)), which can also handle multi-row inserts. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql/

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you for responding.I tried, but didn't work .request.query('insert -----;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()),function(err,data).But data is undefined.

Comment: @YoshihideNishimoto Post ddl for the table involved - at least the columns that are part of the primary key. Presumably your table has an identity column - do you have a different type of synthetic key?

Comment: @SMor Thank you for responding.I posted the ddl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the OUTPUT clause. Here's an example of the syntax...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('RandomTest.dbo.FeatureID_Capture', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.FeatureID_Capture;
GO      
CREATE TABLE dbo.FeatureID_Capture (
    Id NVARCHAR(50)
    );
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('RandomTest.dbo.Feature', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Feature;
GO  
CREATE TABLE dbo.Feature (  
    id NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_Feature_id
        DEFAULT (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(40), NEWID(), (0))),
    createdAt DATETIMEOFFSET NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT DF_Feature_createdAt
        DEFAULT (CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, SYSUTCDATETIME(), (0))),
    updatedAt DATETIMEOFFSET NULL,
    version TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    deleted BIT NULL
        DEFAULT ((0)),
    title NVARCHAR (10) NULL,
    text NVARCHAR (10) NULL,
    period_from DATETIMEOFFSET NULL,
    period_to DATETIMEOFFSET NULL,
    priority FLOAT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (id ASC)
    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
    );
GO 
--=======================================================

INSERT dbo.Feature (title, text) 
    OUTPUT Inserted.id INTO dbo.FeatureID_Capture(Id)
VALUES ('t 1', 'txt 1'), ('t 2', 'txt 22'), ('t 3', 'txt 333');

-------------------------------------

SELECT *FROM dbo.FeatureID_Capture fic;
```

The output...

```
Id
--------------------------------------------------
4E9EB3CD-AD44-4837-9B87-BBB85308FFBF
B93983B6-C15A-4534-8AC4-EB9404964C09
FAFA678A-8416-490C-A871-3963EAB67B9F
```

Comment: Thank you.This seems to require an IDENTITY column.But Our Table don't have that.I do not know if that is the reason, but the following error will occur."The target table of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot have any enabled triggers"

Comment: It does not... I've updated my example... I removed the IDENTITY(1,1) property and added hand coded ID values to the insert.

Comment: Thank you. hmm... in my case,the id is assigned when inserting... so I cant pass the id to query...

Comment: You're over thinking it... The OUTPUT clause captures everything that gets inserted, no matter how you choose to insert it. The only caveat is that you have to call them as a part of the insert query.

Comment: Thank you for responding.

I tried this

INSERT TABLEA (title, content)
OUTPUT Inserted.id as id INTO TABLE_ID (id)
VALUES ('title', 'Text1') 

but result is...

The target 'TABLEA' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot have any enabled trigger

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Thank you for responding.It is 14.0.700

Comment: Looking at BOL, the OUTPUT clause is supposed to work with Azure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql ... Do you have an existing trigger on TABLEA?

Comment: I'm sorry,I don't know how to get the information.Could you tell me??

Comment: I'm not sure about azure but for on prem versions you can use **SELECT * FROM sys.triggers t WHERE t.parent_id = OBJECT_ID('DatabaseName.schema.TableName');**

Comment: Updated example code to reflect your posted table structure.

Comment: Thank you. it works properly.I can get the id!!By the way, Why should we Drop and Create these table again??Before doing that,it didn't work...

Comment: The drop and create thing is just something I do to make testing easier. Definitely not something you'd want do do with your real data. I'm glad you got it working.